# Should we ever NOT use EventHandler<TEventArgs> for our custom .NET events?

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates

Reading the [official guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-publish-events-that-conform-to-net-framework-guidelines) on publishing events in .NET it says:

> Although events in classes that you define can be based on any valid delegate type, even delegates that return a value, **it is generally recommended that you base your events on the .NET Framework pattern by using EventHandler**, as shown in the following example.

The documentation also mentions that *The .NET Framework 2.0 introduces a generic version of this delegate, EventHandler.*

It then goes on to show an example using `EventHandler`, but also an example using a custom delegate type.

Given that it looks like the custom delegate pattern is not strongly discouraged (it even has an official example), **is it ever beneficial to create our custom delegates instead of subclassing `EventArgs` and using `EventHandler<CustomEventArgs>`?**

Comment: Well, not really, i guess. Although, if you have several events in a class that all feature the same EventArgs type (like `EventHandler<SameEventArgs>`), it could be somewhat beneficial for code readability (or documentation of APIs) to use custom event delegate types with different meaningful descriptive names. (Yeah, i am stretching it here a bit, possibly)

Comment: I would argue that `EventHandler<SameEventArgs>` is actually more readable than `SomeEventDelegate`. Looking at the former, I instantly know its signature, while the later, I have to take a closer look

Comment: I can't think of any particular advantage of delegate properties over event handlers.  Contrariwise, an advantage of events over delegates is that serializers ([other than `BinaryFormatter`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2308620)) know to never serialize events, but will sometimes try to serialize delegate members.  See e.g. [C# Deserialize an object which is derived and has references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42602946) for an example of the troubles this can cause.